how do I constrain a shape key
I made a corrective shape key for a model's hip area, and it works fine when the leg bends forward. But if the leg bends back, the shape key also activates, and then there's a bulge in the upper thigh area. So is there a way to add a constraint to the shape key driver?


The_character_model_file

By default, drivers "copy" the driver value to the driven value. In your case, you set up your driver to copy the bone's X rotation value to the shapekey value. Which is incorrect on two levels: your leg bone rotates on the Z axis, and the rotation value where it needs to trigger is from 0 to -0.707 if using Quaternion rotation mode, or from 0 to -90 if using any of the Euler rotation modes.

For this, we need to edit the driver's control curve, which is done in the Drivers Editor. For some reason, yours doesn't have keys, so I just went ahead and deleted the driver and made it again.
I also made an animation of your leg that swings from 0 to 90⁰ back and forth so that we can scroll in the timeline to see the deformation happening and how the driver reacts.
It should look like this:

In the driver editor, with the driver selected in the channel list, you should see the white cursor moving along the curve while the bone rotates. The X axis represents the input value (the bone's Z rotation) and the Y axis represents the driver's value (the shapekey value).
Note that my driver is a scripted expression with just the var as expression, but you could just set it to sum/average value, more on that later. And it uses the Z rotation with auto euler and local space.
Now go in the frame where the bone is at an angle where you want the shapekey to be at 1. Select the key that is at 1 on the Y axis, and move it on the X axis to reach where your white cursor is. Then go to a frame where your shapekey should be at zero, select the key that is ad Y 0, and move it on X to reach the cursor. This will make the shapekey trigger the way you want.


Concerning simple expressions:
I didn't really use them in my answer because using the graph is more visual and easier to understand, but you could use it for many simple graph changes such as yours.
When you needed to invert the driver value (like here you need the negative bone rotation to become a positive value), you could type var*-1 there.
You could even go further and multiply it by the value of the max angle you need to reach. I.E if you need your driver to be at 1 when the bone is at -0.707 (the quaternion equivalent of 90⁰), you could use var*-0.707.
Just a good thing to know, as it's actually a frequent need with shapekeys and whatnot. And it can be faster to do than editing the curve manually.

hey, thanks for showing me how to use the driver editor!

You welcome. I added some more info about simple expressions too.
